# Bootstrap datetimepicker - override click on calendar icon event

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using Mallot Datetime picker (http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) which is a folk of bootstrap-datetimepicker.

I want to override on click event of the calendar icon (displayed right after the calendar text field) so when clicking on the icon, if the calendar popup is showing, it will be closing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Please notice the "autoclose" attribute, set it as true.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        startDate: "2013-02-14 10:00",
        minuteStep: 10
    });
</script>
```

Comment: hi @timber, I tried autoclose but it's not working.As my understanding, "autoclose" is used for "picking/selecting date event" not for clicking on the calendar icon (on the right hand side, right after the text field) event